# Lambda Calculus Equivalence

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm a bit new to lambda calculus and was wondering about the equivalence of two expressions

$$(\lambda x.\lambda y.xy)\lambda z.z\overset{?}=(\lambda x.\lambda y.xy)(\lambda z.z)$$

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Please make sure that I didn’t introduce any errors when I converted to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: No, looks good. Thanks.

Comment: In $\lambda$-calculus the $\lambda$ symbol behaves  similarly to a quantifier and its scope spans until the enclosing parenthesis or end of term. The two expressions are equivalent _syntactically_.

Comment: @dtldarek I'm not sure what you mean by syntactically - if they're equivalent syntactically, aren't they equivalent generally as well?

Comment: I believe that @dtldarek is saying that the difference is purely cosmetic, like that between $\exists x\varphi(x)$ and $\exists x\big(\varphi(x)\big)$, and hence that the two are trivially equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention the outer most parenthesis are dropped for minimal clutter.
$$\color{red}{(\lambda x.\lambda y.xy)}\color{blue}{\lambda z.z}\iff\color{red}{(\lambda x.\lambda y.xy)}\color{blue}{(\lambda z.z)}$$
The same thing is done in algebra:
$$\color{red}{(z)}\color{blue}{(x+y)}\iff \color{red}z\color{blue}{(x+y)}$$
In lambda calculus there is a similar "order of operations" as in conventional mathematics. Things to note are parenthesis are evaluated first.